# Unable to detect origin of CustomizedTextParser error creeping in logs

Tags: android

```
04-03 19:46:46.921 10152-10412/ D/CustomizedTextParser: 
Initialzed
 04-03 19:46:46.921 10152-10412/ E/CustomizedTextParser: 
getCustomizedText Rule is empty. mRuleMap={}
04-03 19:46:50.921 10152-10412/ E/CustomizedTextParser: 
getCustomizedText Rule is empty. mRuleMap={}
```

My logs are showing this error and clearly it takes up about 4 seconds. How do I trace the origin of this error?

The code being executed when the logs appear

```
Collections.sort(packages, new 
ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(mPackageManager));
```

which essentially takes a list of installed packages on the device and sorts it alphabetically with respect to name of the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected this by replacing the method of loading the installed packages. For anyone having the same issue, the old method and new method are:

Old method

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = 
mPackageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

// Sorts the list in alphabetical order of app name
Collections.sort(packages, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(mPackageManager));
```

New method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> activities = mPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
Collections.sort(activities, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(mPackageManager));
```

Comment: I ran into this as well and I believe it is a Samsung specific problem. I booted a Samsung Galaxy S6 and the whole LogCat was full with this message, so I believe it's a benign issue (makes you wonder why it's logged under "Error"...).